# socket.io-client connecting, but not emitting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am making a little encrypted chat app, in the terminal, using socket.io-client and socket.io. The client is able to connect to the server, but is not emitting the username, when its entered.

Client:

```
 var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
 socket.on('connect_error', function(){
console.log('Failed to establish a connection to the servers, or lost     connection');

 return process.exit();     
  });
 var prompt = require("prompt-sync")()
 var news = "Add news: Will be from database. " 
 var username = prompt("Username>: ")

 console.log("Hold on a sec, just checking that!")
 console.log("")
 if (typeof username === "defined"){
 socket.emit('user-name', {usr: 'username'})
 }


socket.on('user-name-good',function(socket){
console.log("Okay! Your username looks good, we just require your password")
console.log("If you chose to have no password, please press enter with    out pressing space!")
 var password = prompt("Password>: ")
  if (typeof password !== "defined"){
    console.log("Please provide a password!")
    return password = prompt("Username>: ")
 }

 socket.on('user-name-fail',function(socket){
 console.log("Sorry, we could not find, "+username+""+"Please register    on the website, or, if you have registered ")
 return process.exit()
})    

}
)
```

Server code, is based on code from socket.io chat example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
io.emit('chat message', msg);
});
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I have added a error event, this closes the client if a connection to the server fails, so I know its connecting, any help appreciated, I have done research on this topic, and tried a lot of other methods, but to no avail.

Also the connection is made after you submit data, not when the client code is started, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send events between client and server you have to:

Send event A from client to the server and server has to be listening for the A event.

If you want to send event B from server to client then client has to be listening for the event B.

Apart from everything else in your code I don't see where you are listening for the 'chat message' event on the client side.

Socket.io is based on these so called 'events'. The code below is going to send 'my_event' event to the server and the trasmitted data is going to be the object { a: 1 }.

```
socket.emit('my_event', { a: 1 });
```

If I want to handle this event on the server I have to listen for it:

```
socket.on('my_event', function(data) {
    // data is the object { a: 1 }
    // do stuff..
});
```

Comment: I was focusing on the login, hadn't got around to the chat message.

Comment: How do I use the data sent to the server from the client? like, if (a === "foo"){console.log("a === "foo"}.

Comment: On the client side write something like: socket.emit('eventA', 'foo'); And on the server side add: socket.on('eventA', function(data){ console.log(data); }); It will display the 'foo' string in the console on the server. Try that and you'll get how it works. Also if you check typeof username === "defined" .. it is never going to work because the typeof keyword doesn't ever return 'defined'. Prompt will assign a string to the username variable, so you can simply check: if(username){ // do stuff.. }

Comment: Perfect! That fixed it. Thank you!