# socket.io emit not working

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am a newbie to the socket.io world and I was trying a simple program as below

Server Side

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('socket listening.');
socket.on('chat_message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
      });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client Code Snippet

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat_message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
</script>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send</input>
    </form>
  </body>
```

So here I cannot see the messages getting printed.Can someone help me understand the reason for the same?

As a try I did the following thing too at the server side.

```
 io.on('chat_message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
      });
```

Still that didn't work.

I try referring the link below but unable to understand the reason for the same.

[socket.io-client connecting, but not emitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229266/socket-io-client-connecting-but-not-emitting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script tag should reside in `<head>` or `<body>` element; yours isn't inside any. so first move them inside your body tag at the end to ensure DOM is loaded before running scripts.

Your first input does not have any type. add `type="text"` so you can retrieve its value.

You have closed second input tag. `<input>` tag is self-closing. no need to be closed. ( you could set the value through `value` attribute: `value="Send"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>socket.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="m" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat_message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```